# JBoss Messaging and Thread Priority

Tags: jboss, jboss-mdb

I'm using JBoss 5.1.0 GA together with JMS.

I have two message-driven beans.

Could someone explain the threading model to me?  For example, does each MDB have a separate thread pool?  Do they share a global pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo. That's the one I have been looking for. I have been trying different options and the number of threads still grew regardless of config like below.Jboss really has poor documentation.

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "xx")
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question.  All message-driven beans share a common thread pool that can be configured in jca-jboss-beans.xml in the deploy directory.